# is "reads as" equal to "similar to" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity, phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

> For all their efforts, the diplomats at Versailles achieved the precise opposite of what they had set out to do, **inexorably, tragically laying the groundwork for the next, more horrible world war.**
>
> In this sense, then, the story of diplomacy also reads as a cautionary tale.
>
> source: [diplomacy VSI](https://books.google.com/books?id=i0sTiwJQMi0C&pg=PT20&lpg=PT20&dq=In%20this%20sense,%20then,%20the%20story%20of%20diplomacy%20also%20reads%20as%20a%20cautionary%20tale.&source=bl&ots=0eqkuj0R8J&sig=1TQ887HzjVVporJAgdM7kFk2R2M&hl=fa&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi3sO7a0_LLAhXE1ywKHe9gD-QQ6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=In%20this%20sense%2C%20then%2C%20the%20story%20of%20diplomacy%20also%20reads%20as%20a%20cautionary%20tale.&f=false)

Can I say that "reads as" equal to "similar to" in this context? the entence saying that history of diplomacy is a warning tale for us (?)

Comment: "also proves a cautionary tale"

Comment: can you explain more?

Comment: You need to take into account the *also*: *"also reads as"* ⟶ *"can be viewed as"*.

Comment: Hi @yorgun.  I want to invite you, and everyone commenting/answering/voting here, to participate in [this meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/7916/13804)

Answer (score 1):

[Allen165 at Using English.com](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/109077-read-to-mean-vs-read-as-meaning) answers the question

> *Which is better: "read to mean" or "read as meaning"?* [in]
>
> [a] Accordingly, although the Court stated that such rules do not
>   constitute a restriction on the freedom to provide services, this
>   should be read to mean that they constitute a justifiable restriction;
>   whether the restriction is justified or not hinges on the
>   proportionality of the rules in question.
>
> [b] Accordingly, although the Court stated that such rules do not
>   constitute a restriction on the freedom to provide services, this
>   should be read as meaning that they constitute a justifiable
>   restriction; whether the restriction is justified or not hinges on the
>   proportionality of the rules in question.

with:

> ... they are both possible.

I'd add

(1) 'this should be read as meaning' is equivalent to 'this should be interpreted as meaning'

(2) 'reads as' in the original question is really a transformed way of saying 'should / must be understood to mean/signify' (a 'middle voice' usage; compare We drink this wine <= .. => This wine drinks well). It might perhaps be paraphrased as 'comes across as' (though this latter leaves more scope for querying how strong the implication is).